# Accessing variables from scopes

Tags: c++

```
void testing(){
    cout << it << endl;
};


int main(){
int it = 99;   
testing();
return 0;
}
```

This is probably a real rookie and basic question but how can i access the variable it within the function testing without passing it as an argument?

Or is the scope a function can access defined by where it is defined.
for example, testing defined in global scope, cannot access main function scope?

Comment: You should not be accessing variables not passed as arguments unless you have to.

Comment: You can move the declaration of `it` outside the functions, rendering it a global variable.  You have to declare it before first use, i.e. above `testing()`.

Comment: Without changing the scope of `it`, you can't. `testing` is not enclosed by `main`, functions within functions is not a thing in C++ (but look into lambda expressions), so `testing` cannot see `main`'s internals.

Comment: That said, you can delve into undefined behaviour and do all sorts of things [some would consider... unnatural.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIHF8Xe-O6Y)

Comment: *"without passing `it` as an argument"*. Why ?

Comment: From the horse's mouth: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope

Comment: Just for learning purpose jeebus christ

Comment: Not much to learn here, I'm afraid. You can't do it without stepping outside what the language decrees to be legal, and doing it illegally differs from implementation to implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the variable making it a global variable.

```
int it;

void testing(){ 
    cout << it << endl; 
}; 

int main(){ 
    it = 99; 
    testing(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

But you should avoid using global variables. Since every function can access these it can be hard to figure out which functions actually access and modify these variables.

You should prefer passing variables between functions as it makes you code easier to read and you can avoid errors like unwanted value overrides.

Comment: Recommending usage of global variables is probably the worst advice to give. At least show appropriate alternatives.

Comment: That's why I added "you should avoid"

Comment: Nah. Diving into the stack with pointers and UB would be worse.

Comment: @FreshD That's why I said _"At least show appropriate alternatives."_

Comment: Updated the answer. Fine for you or did you have something else in mind.